# How can I affect the starting point of "paste in place"-coordinates?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

I want to copy an object element from one page to another page with a different page height. The elements should have the same coordinates on x and y axis. The "Paste in Place" functions doesn't behave like I want it to.

I think the following picture will explain this far better than I can with this text.

Do you know how to resolve this issue?

[image: InDesign Paste in Place]

Comment: But that's not the same place. If you want to adjust the layout then *Liquid Layout* is your best option I think.

Comment: Appears to be pasting in place to me.... just because your page size has changed, it doesn't change the coordinates of the paste.

Comment: Maybe I should ask differently: 
How can I copy an element and paste it at the same coordinates, regardless of the pages size.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's no mechanism to keep *anything* relative to the page/canvas/artboard edge in any Adobe application, which is what you are asking. I think this is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

From http://creativepro.com/indesign-how-using-liquid-layout/

> **Liquid Layout** can move and/or resize objects for you any time you change the page size or orientation—and not just for digital output
>   formats. It’s highly useful when working with multiple print formats,
>   too. For example, let’s say you’re laying out a non-fiction book, and
>   that you’ll be producing both hardcover and trade paperback versions
>   of it. For most designers that usually means two completely different
>   layouts, built independently of one another, with text poured in from
>   Word docs and figures, sidebars, etc. manually positioned separately
>   for each version. For more-savvy layout artists who use anchored
>   objects and such, the workflow is usually to create a copy of the
>   hardcover layout, enable Layout Adjustment, and resize the pages.
>   Layout Adjustment will do much of the heavy lifting to reflow and
>   reposition anchored objects, but there’s still a lot of manual cleanup
>   to be done. With Liquid Layouts, the workflow is: create the hardcover
>   edition with anchored objects, prep the objects to resize when needed,
>   create a copy for the paperback edition, resize the pages, and perform
>   minimal manual cleanup. If you need a third edition—maybe a
>   large-print or an on-screen or on-tablet version—that’s just as easy
>   to create, because the original version was prepped to change to any
>   page size, any format.

So unless your workflow relies completely on copy and paste, a few rules and page adjustments should do it for you. Duplicate the document or page and adjust the page size and the object adjustment should do the rest.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no way or preferences settings to really insert a copied element exactly at the same coordinate relative to the document that welcomes the "placed" elements.

---

But there are some good old tricks that can save you some time. Maybe you already know them. Personally, I love using the coordinate numbers because it's the most precise way to align elements and verify if they're aligned without any guide.

**1) Use the coordinate XY, and insert these values in the new document when you do your paste in place.** Also make sure the coordinates are relative to the top left corner, so your point 0.0 starts there, it's easier this way. On your example, the X is alright and you'll only need to add the value in the Y field.

The downside is that you need to remember exactly the coordinate numbers or note them down, and type them again.

[image: Paste in place using coordinates in InDesign]

**2) That's a trick if you need to do a lot of copy paste on many elements and don't want to note down the coordinates**. Simply trace a small transparent square and put it on the corner 0.0 on the coordinates XY. Then group it or select it together with the other elements you need to move, and do your "copy/paste" as you normally do.

When you'll do a paste in place or a normal paste, all you'll need to do is to type 0.0 in the XY coordinate boxes to place it at the right position, at 0.0. From what I see from your example, the X value will already be at "0", and you'll simply need to insert a "0" on the Y.

This works better if you don't have anything going outside of you paper size though and it's really a shortcut that doesn't fit all situations but still very useful.

[image: Using shortcut tricks for coordinates in Indesign]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Good trick with the transparent box.